# how Byte Address memory in Altera FPGA?

Tags: memory, architecture, fpga, addressing

I worked with megafunctions to generate 32bit data memory in the fpga.but the output was addressed 32bit (4 bytes) at time , how to do 1 byte addressing ?
i have Altera Cyclone IV ep4ce6e22c8.

Comment: For a good answer we need more information. But likely: for reads you need to select the right byte lane, for writes you have to generate a memory with byte-write enables.

Comment: I'm designing a 32bit CPU in fpga , the ram is 32bit address input and 32bit output data. i used lpm_ram_dq from mega functions in Quartus 2 for the ram, but the problem is it addresses 32bit (bytes) not single individual bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm designing a 32bit CPU in fpga ,

Nowadays every CPU address bus works in bytes. Thus to access your 32-bit wide memory you should NOT connect the LS 2 address bits. You can use the A[1:0] address bits to select a byte (or half word using A[1] only) from the memory when your read.

You still will need four byte write enable signals. This allows you to write word, half-words or bytes.

Have a look at existing CPU buses or existing connection standards like AHB or AXI.

---

Post edit:

> but reading address 0001 , i get 0x05060708 but the desired value is 0x02030405.

What you are trying to do is read a word from a non-aligned address. There is no existing 32-bit wide memory that supports that. I suggest you have a look at how a 32-bit wide memory works.

The old Motorola 68020 architecture supported that. It requires a special memory controller which first reads the data from address 0 and then from address 4 and re-combines the data into a new 32-bit word.

With the cost of memory dropping and reducing CPU cycles becoming more important, no modern CPU supports that. They throw an exception: non-aligned memory access.

You have several choices:

1. Build a special memory controller which supports unaligned accesses.
2. Adjust your expectations.

I would go for the latter. In general it is based on the wrong idea how a memory works. As consolidation: You are not the first person on this website who thinks that is how you read words from memory.